# simple_salesforce python : sf.instance.bulk.query gives index error

Tags: python, soql, simple-salesforce

So I am trying to query from the salesforce using the python simple_salesforce library:
The query is a Select like shown below:

```
sf.bulk.instance.query("SELECT  field_1, field_2 from table__c WHERE name IN ('1', '2' ...2000 values)")
```

The tuple I pass has about 2000 values. So when I try to use sf.query it is giving back 414 or the connection get aborted(sometimes it gives URI too long). Then I tried to use the sf.bulk where I can go up to **1300** values, but after that it is giving **index error: list index out of range**. This is raised from **_get_batch_results**.

For now I have **split** the tuple into parts and made multiple queries to sf.bulk query which I think is not efficient. Could anyone provide me a solution for this?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because your query is too long and of course this is due to your very long `WHERE ... IN` condition.

My suggestion is to throw the values you have in the `IN` in a temporary table a rewrite the query as a join between the two tables.

If you can create a second table, `table__d`, with the list of values, then your query can look like:

```
SELECT field_1, field_2 
  FROM table__c 
 WHERE name IN (SELECT name from table__d)
```

Alternatively you can split your query in 2 queries with 1000 values each, or even in smaller chunks.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I do not understand the part about joining, since this is related to just a single table.Could you shed some light on that? And for your info this works in case of 1300 values. Anything above that gives me back error

Comment: I have added the query, but also an additional suggestion. The 414 error is caused by the query too long, just make it shorter :D